# How can I make GDataXML ignore comments?

Tags: cocoa, xml-parsing, xml-comments, gdataxml

When GDataXML parses this line

```
<choices array="YES" > <!-- for now, the first answer is the right one -->
```

It gives me the comment `for now, the first answer is the right one` as a child element. Is this expected behavior for an XMLParser? How can I tell GDataXML to ignore comments?

Thanks,

z.

Comment: I have seen this behavior as well and it is VERY ODD why this would be the default behavior. How do you turn this feature off?